# PropertyDescriptorCollection - Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, propertydescriptor, icustomtypedescriptor

I have a PropertyGrid with a SelectedObject of an object of type `class1`.

I am implementing the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface for the `class1` object, and I am getting a `PropertyDescriptorCollection` from another object `class2`, and needing to display the `class2` `PropertyDescriptors` in a PropertyGrid as well as the `class1` `PropertyDescriptors`.

I am getting the following error displayed in the PropertyGrid for the `class2` `PropertyDescriptors`:

> Object does not match target type.

Here is my code that works without the `class2` `PropertyDescriptors`:

```
public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
    var propertyDescriptors = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptorCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        propertyDescriptors.Add(propertyDescriptorCollection[i]);
    }
    return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propertyDescriptors.ToArray());
}
```

Here is the code that I am working on:

```
public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
    var propertyDescriptors = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptorCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        propertyDescriptors.Add(propertyDescriptorCollection[i]);
    }
    var class2PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(class2);
    for (int i = 0; i < class2PropertyDescriptorCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        propertyDescriptors.Add(class2PropertyDescriptorCollection[i]);
    }
    return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propertyDescriptors.ToArray());
}
```

How can I display the `PropertyDescriptors` from `class2`, when the `PropertyDescriptors` from `class1` are displayed in a PropertyGrid?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared propertyDescriptorCollection as type PropertyDescriptorCollection, but have used var for the class2PropertyDescriptorCollection.  What if you tried the following:

```
public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
    var propertyDescriptors = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptorCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        propertyDescriptors.Add(propertyDescriptorCollection[i]);
    }
    PropertyDescriptorCollection class2PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(class2);
    for (int i = 0; i < class2PropertyDescriptorCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        propertyDescriptors.Add(class2PropertyDescriptorCollection[i]);
    }
    return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propertyDescriptors.ToArray());
}
```